# Dúvida na implementação do Rotativa em asp net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Estou com um problema com rotativa para geração PDF, onde estou colocando uma imagem colorida porém ao gerar o relatório a mesma aparece em preto e branco e não colorida como devia aparecer. Há algum procedimento a ser feito? Estou a chamar minha imagem desta forma no meu arquivo html:

```
<div>
    <img src="@Server.MapPath("~/Images/logo_relatorio.png")"/>
</div>
```

Comment: coisa estranha. Como você gera esse relatório? Não é configuração por exemplo do seu navegador que está para  não imprimir em colorido?

Comment: Então não consegui encontrar nenhuma configuração do meu navegador sobre este caso, estou utilizando o google chrome e esta ativado o seu plugin de visualização de pdf. Mais salvando o pdf e abrir novamente em um leitor tais como do proprio windows 10 ou adobe reader a imagem ainda fica preto e branco e não colorida. Também ja testei em outros navegadores e esta ocorrendo o mesmo problema.

Comment: Me responde como está gerando esse relatório? Você está dando um comando javascript para imprimir a janela ou é outra coisa, algum componente?

Comment: Estou chamando num action link, onde passo o nome da minha action e o nome da controller, sendo assim ao acionar o actionlink na  minha action na minha controller retorna para uma view que e o meu html onde esta a chamada da imagem e ja em seguida gera na tela esse html como pdf utilizando o rotativa onde esta sendo configurada nesta action da controller.

Comment: Problema resolvido ao alterar a propriedade  pdf.IsGrayScale para false a mesma estava como true assim deixando todo relatorio em preto e branco, valeu galera...